# PHP Injecting class variables

Tags: php

I have a class variable

```
private $email;
```

I then have a string

```
$xml = '<domDoc>';
$xml .= '<recipient xtkschema="nms:recipient" operation="insert"   email="myemail@me.com" />';
$xml .= '</domDoc>';

$params = array('sessiontoken' => $sessionToken, 'domDoc' => new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML));
```

In my xml string, instead of the email being hardcoded, I need to inject the variable.  I have tried the following but it does not seem to work

```
$xml .= '<recipient xtkschema="nms:recipient" _operation="insert"  email=' .$this->email.' />';
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: then I assume `$this->email` is empty. What happens if you echo it?

Comment: Add string delimiter to `email="'.$this->email.'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting your string delimiter for the `email` attribute. Your current code looks like this:

```
$xml .= '<recipient xtkschema="nms:recipient" _operation="insert"  email=' .$this->email.' />';
```

Assuming the value of `$this->email` is "user@example.com", once PHP is run, your HTML will look like:

```
$xml .= '<recipient xtkschema="nms:recipient" _operation="insert"  email=user@example.com />';
```

Notice that for the `email` attribute, it is missing the string delimiter around the value. Simply add the double quotes inside your string and you will be set!

```
$xml .= '<recipient xtkschema="nms:recipient" _operation="insert"  email="' .$this->email.'" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use :

`$xml .= '<recipient xtkschema="nms:recipient" _operation="insert"  email="' .$this->email.'" />';`

instead of

`$xml .= '<recipient xtkschema="nms:recipient" _operation="insert"  email=' .$this->email.' />';`